# Unable to delete row : TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

There are several posts on this question but still not getting the solution.
This the parent class Userr. 
In a @OneToMany relationship I want to remove a particular child Account.

Now When I do this by "DELETE" query I am getting following exception.

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaEntity
@RooJpaActiveRecord(finders = { "findUserrsByUserName"})
public class Userr {


@NotNull
@Column(unique = true)
private String userName;


@NotNull
private int userType;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
}
```

Child class

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
@RooJpaEntity
public class Account {

@OneToMany(mappedBy="account", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();


/*@OneToMany(mappedBy="account", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<PremiumPlayPositionCombination> premiumPlayPosition = new ArrayList<PremiumPlayPositionCombination>();*/


@OneToMany(mappedBy="account", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<PositionCombinationArc> allPositionsArc = new ArrayList<PositionCombinationArc>();

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
private Userr user;
}
```

Here is my delete query

```
@Transactional
public static void deleteClientByClientId(Long clientId) {
    System.out.println("Delete query findUsersClientsByUser" + clientId);
    int deleteCount= entityManager().createQuery("DELETE FROM Account where id =:clientId").setParameter("clientId", clientId).executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("Delete query findUsersClientsByUser" + deleteCount);



}
```

I have added in ApplicationContext-security.xml like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"      xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
<!--
    This will automatically locate any and all property files you have
    within your classpath, provided they fall under the META-INF/spring
    directory. The located property files are parsed and their values can
    then be used within application context files in the form of
    ${propertyKey}.
-->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>
<!--
    Turn on AspectJ @Configurable support. As a result, any time you
    instantiate an object, Spring will attempt to perform dependency
    injection on that object. This occurs for instantiation via the "new"
    keyword, as well as via reflection. This is possible because AspectJ
    is used to "weave" Roo-based applications at compile time. In effect
    this feature allows dependency injection of any object at all in your
    system, which is a very useful feature (without @Configurable you'd
    only be able to dependency inject objects acquired from Spring or
    subsequently presented to a specific Spring dependency injection
    method). Roo applications use this useful feature in a number of
    areas, such as @PersistenceContext injection into entities.
-->
<context:spring-configured/>
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <property name="port" value="587"/>
    <property name="username" value="noreply@uforic.in"/>
    <property name="password" value="noreply@123"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<!--
    This declaration will cause Spring to locate every @Component,
    @Repository and @Service in your application. In practical terms this
    allows you to write a POJO and then simply annotate the new POJO as an
    @Service and Spring will automatically detect, instantiate and
    dependency inject your service at startup time. Importantly, you can
    then also have your new service injected into any other class that
    requires it simply by declaring a field for your service inside the
    relying class and Spring will inject it. Note that two exclude filters
    are declared. The first ensures that Spring doesn't spend time
    introspecting Roo-specific ITD aspects. The second ensures Roo doesn't
    instantiate your @Controller classes, as these should be instantiated
    by a web tier application context. Refer to web.xml for more details
    about the web tier application context setup services.

    Furthermore, this turns on @Autowired, @PostConstruct etc support. These 
    annotations allow you to use common Spring and Java Enterprise Edition 
    annotations in your classes without needing to do any special configuration. 
    The most commonly used annotation is @Autowired, which instructs Spring to
    dependency inject an object into your class.
-->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.uforic.optionstrader">
    <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
    <!--context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/-->
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: so you need a TRANSACTION around it like the message says. And? where is your transaction?

Comment: The relevant point in your question is how are you configuring the transactions in your application, you should add that to the question. `deleteClientByClientId` is being executed without a transaction and failing.

Comment: @NeilStockton edited the qustion . It's there and still shows the same error

Comment: @DavidSN edited the qustion . It's there now and still shows the same error

Comment: You should add your Transaction configuration in Spring. The annotation is there, but it is not being executed inside a transaction.

Comment: @DavidSN something like this ?? edited the question after adding

Comment: @DavidSN still getting the same error even after adding into configuration file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check following things in your code:

1. If you are using spring based transaction then make sure you import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional class for @Transactional annotation
   In your case it might be javax.transaction.Transactional
2. I see deleteClientByClientId method in your code as static. @Transactional in spring does not have support for static methods. Make your method non static which is annotated as transactional.
   You can refer [@Transactional with static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569732/transactional-with-static-method)

Let me know, which option works for you.

Comment: I know its silly, but option 1 worked for me after banging my head for 2 hours :D

Answer (score 0):

In Spring context file you need to add below code:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

Also, add your `spring security` bean configuration.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to update/delete using Hibernate, it is mendatory to surround the query by a transaction Begin() and Commit() example :

```
EntityTransaction tr=em.getTransaction();
tr.begin();

Query query = (Query) em.createQuery( "update etudiant set  email= :em, adresse= :adr,telephone= :tele,password= :pwd"
        + " where email= :mail");
        query.setParameter("em", email)
        .setParameter("adr", adresse)
        .setParameter("tele", tele)
        .setParameter("pwd", pass)
        .setParameter("mail", ancienEmail);
        
int a= query.executeUpdate();
tr.commit();
```