# Lazy Initialization Exception inside static util method

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a service:

```
@Override
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
public Seller doSomething(MyDto myDto) {
  final MyObject myObject = myDao.findById(myDto.getId());

  //do various things to myObject

  StateChooser.calculateNewState(myObject);
}
```

In the implementation of `calculateNewState`, various `LAZY` collections are retrieved via an `EAGER` object:

```
public static void calculateNewState(MyObject myObject) {
  List<MyOtherObject> otherObjects = myObject.getEagerObject().getMyLazyCollection();
  //etc

  myObject.setStatus(calculatedNewStatus);
}
```

But I get a Lazy Initialisation Exception on the call to `getMyLazyCollection`. This collection is an `@ElementCollection`, if that makes any difference.

I know that the object needs to be attached to the Hibernate session in order that the proxy can go to the database, but I don't understand how the object is becoming detached.

I have tried the following 'configurations' of the method calculateNewState:

- static method of a util class (as in the example above) with no annotations
- implemented in a `@Component`

  - with `@Transactional`
  - with `@Transactional(PROPAGATION_MANDATORY)`
  - without `@Transactional`

They all result in the same exception: "could not initialize proxy - no Session"

What am I doing wrong?

The aim of the `calculateNewState` method is to calculate the object's state before it is persisted to the database - I just want the logic to be shared so that it can be called from various different methods that change the object's data.

## Edit

Just to clarify, the static method isn't annotated at all, and is only called from inside a method annotated with `@Transaction`. The object passed to the static method is loaded from a DAO inside the `@Transaction` method.

Comment: it's because `calculateNewState ` is a static method. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569732/transactional-with-static-method

Comment: But I'm not trying to proxy the static method. Isn't it the entity that is proxied for the lazy getters and the (at)Components that are proxied to start transactions with the (at)Transactional method?

Comment: indeed, sorry for trying to close this one. The truth is that I don't know either. I hope someone has the time to respond to this

Comment: can u try `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()`inside your static method and see if there is a transaction active there?