# @BeforeAll and @Transaction are not working - changes on db side are not rollbacked

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm trying to test my application using `@Transactional` to rollback after the tests and `@BeforeAll` to set up the objects for tests:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class UserScoreTest {
    @BeforeAll
    public static void init() {
       userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Test
    ...
}
```

The problem seems to be that once `@BeforeAll` is executed, the changes are "committed".

Does anybody know if it's desired behavior or it's a bug?

I solved my problems using @BeforeEach and then saving during in the @Test and it works (after tests, everything is rollbacked) but I would prefer to set up once with @BeforeAll.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that @Transactional only works on instance methods of the Spring "Bean", not on static methods. That is why it works for @BeforeEach instance method but not on @BeforeAll static method.

One way around this would be to use @BeforeEach but have a boolean field that stores if it has already been done once. Don't forget to address threading issue if your test runs in a multi-threaded manner.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23570400/905762) explains it better.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your concept is wrong.

In common test scenario, any @Autowired dependency, like your userRepository, should not be static. I suppose it is static as you are referencing it from the static method.

You should consider @Before annotation only and thanks to the @Transactional annotation, each test will be automatically rollbacked at the end.

The main scenario is this:

Run @BeforeAll

For each @Test annotation:

- Begin transaction
- Run @Before
- Run @Test
- Run @After
- Rollback transaction

The purpose of @BeforeAll is to do some work only once for entire test class. I can think of one possible scenario for setting values for RequestContextHolder or SecurityContextHolder but I would be aware of loosing those values in other threads (if @Test creates some). I rarely use @BeforeAll. Same principle is for @Parameterized tests which have to have @Parameters annotation above the static method. This is because the runner in @RunWith has to know how many tests and which parameters to use before actual initialization of the test.

@BeforeAll is out of transaction scope.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I used '@BeforeAll' to create the beans that I can use in all tests. Ex. Create 2 players, create a game and then play in different tests. It doesn't make sense to create players, a game before each test, so I think it's not wrong to use it but it doesn't work here. The workaround, as '@John B' said, is to create '@BeforeEach' with a boolean and execute it only once

Answer (score -2):

@BeforeEach executes for every @Test, @BeforeAll executes only once at start for all the @Test

Comment: That's true but that is not an answer to my question and this is more a comment than an answer.